# create_or_update custom model results in ResourceExistsError

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure Machine Learning, where I created a component in Designer that receives a dataset as input, trains a model on an A100 cluster with 4 GPUs, and saves a custom model in a folder. I now want to publish this model into the models, so I do:

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Model
...
ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)  

train(config)
if config.get("training_completed", False):
    folder_model = Model(
        path=config.result_path, # this is result_path: "" in the config file
        type=AssetTypes.CUSTOM_MODEL,
        name="donut-azureml-retrain-test",
        description="Model created by cloud training.",
    )
    with torch.cuda.device(0):
        ml_client.models.create_or_update(folder_model)
```

config.result_path is where the model and its artifacts are saved during training. Training finishes just fine, and I also do get the latest version of the model under Models, HOWEVER, the job still fails, as the component also throws an error. Apparently, `create_or_update` wants to write to some blob storage that already exists. I don't know what or where as that's missing from the error message, and I also don't understand why it would as each run creates its own folder for each run.

Any idea what I need to be doing to avoid having this error? The code already does what I want, it's just that the error stops the pipeline. I've read that some issues might be cause by the concurrency of several writes to the same blob from several processes, so I specifically restricted the `create_or_update` to just be called from 1 GPU to avoid that, but to no avail.

I went into the storage and checked that the model files are actually saved within the folder that's created for the job, so it's saved to like: workspaceblobstore/LocalUpload/cc117089efafcc77981f87c488b09aa5/output_model/cloud_train/2024-01-23_17-34-35/

The stack trace:

```
Epoch 29: 100%|██████████| 47/47 [02:16<00:00,  2.90s/it, loss=0.0784, v_num=2-39]`Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_epochs=30` reached.
Epoch 29: 100%|██████████| 47/47 [02:16<00:00,  2.90s/it, loss=0.0784, v_num=2-39]
[32mUploading output_model (2601.0 MBs):   0%|          | 0/2600999944 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

[32mUploading output_model (2601.0 MBs):  38%|███▊      | 985196781/2600999944 [00:03<00:05, 314891330.97it/s]
[32mUploading output_model (2601.0 MBs): 100%|██████████| 2600999944/2600999944 [00:04<00:00, 561598211.78it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/azureml/cr/j/1e97a97a297a46a3bb294ca3e3d6a0d3/exe/wd/train.py", line 186, in <module>
    main(args, left_argv)
  File "/mnt/azureml/cr/j/1e97a97a297a46a3bb294ca3e3d6a0d3/exe/wd/train.py", line 171, in main
    ml_client.models.create_or_update(folder_model)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_telemetry/activity.py", line 275, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/operations/_model_operations.py", line 266, in create_or_update
    raise ex
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/operations/_model_operations.py", line 211, in create_or_update
    model, indicator_file = _check_and_upload_path(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 497, in _check_and_upload_path
    uploaded_artifact = _upload_to_datastore(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 382, in _upload_to_datastore
    artifact = upload_artifact(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 241, in upload_artifact
    artifact_info = storage_client.upload(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_blob_storage_helper.py", line 120, in upload
    upload_directory(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_asset_utils.py", line 678, in upload_directory
    future.result()  # access result to propagate any exceptions
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_asset_utils.py", line 566, in upload_file
    storage_client.container_client.upload_blob(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py", line 1101, in upload_blob
    blob.upload_blob(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 765, in upload_blob
    return upload_block_blob(**options)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 195, in upload_block_blob
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 184, in process_storage_error
    exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 105, in upload_block_blob
    response = client.upload(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_block_blob_operations.py", line 864, in upload
    map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/exceptions.py", line 164, in map_error
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: The specified blob already exists.
RequestId:3f70f718-a01e-0007-4854-4ec34a000000
Time:2024-01-23T23:34:45.4991590Z
ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobAlreadyExists</Code><Message>The specified blob already exists.
RequestId:3f70f718-a01e-0007-4854-4ec34a000000
Time:2024-01-23T23:34:45.4991590Z</Message></Error>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 186, in <module>
    main(args, left_argv)
  File "train.py", line 171, in main
    ml_client.models.create_or_update(folder_model)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_telemetry/activity.py", line 275, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/operations/_model_operations.py", line 266, in create_or_update
    raise ex
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/operations/_model_operations.py", line 211, in create_or_update
    model, indicator_file = _check_and_upload_path(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 497, in _check_and_upload_path
    uploaded_artifact = _upload_to_datastore(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 382, in _upload_to_datastore
    artifact = upload_artifact(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_artifact_utilities.py", line 241, in upload_artifact
    artifact_info = storage_client.upload(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_artifacts/_blob_storage_helper.py", line 120, in upload
    upload_directory(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_asset_utils.py", line 678, in upload_directory
    future.result()  # access result to propagate any exceptions
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/ai/ml/_utils/_asset_utils.py", line 566, in upload_file
    storage_client.container_client.upload_blob(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py", line 1101, in upload_blob
    blob.upload_blob(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 765, in upload_blob
    return upload_block_blob(**options)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 195, in upload_block_blob
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 184, in process_storage_error
    exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 105, in upload_block_blob
    response = client.upload(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_block_blob_operations.py", line 864, in upload
    map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/exceptions.py", line 164, in map_error
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: The specified blob already exists.
RequestId:af0469a5-d01e-0050-1d54-4e6d79000000
Time:2024-01-23T23:34:44.8083864Z
ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobAlreadyExists</Code><Message>The specified blob already exists.
RequestId:af0469a5-d01e-0050-1d54-4e6d79000000
Time:2024-01-23T23:34:44.8083864Z</Message></Error>
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:562:1896 [1] NCCL INFO [Service thread] Connection closed by localRank 1
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:106:1894 [0] NCCL INFO [Service thread] Connection closed by localRank 0
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:562:562 [1] NCCL INFO MSCCL: Teardown finished
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:562:562 [1] NCCL INFO comm 0x83035810 rank 1 nranks 4 cudaDev 1 busId 200000 - Abort COMPLETE

[39m

28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:106:106 [0] NCCL INFO MSCCL: Teardown finished
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:106:106 [0] NCCL INFO comm 0x82ce8b60 rank 0 nranks 4 cudaDev 0 busId 100000 - Abort COMPLETE
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:564:1895 [3] NCCL INFO [Service thread] Connection closed by localRank 3
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:564:564 [3] NCCL INFO MSCCL: Teardown finished
28864c2e4e74430cbfa137cd7b07b87b000000:564:564 [3] NCCL INFO comm 0x83a28570 rank 3 nranks 4 cudaDev 3 busId 400000 - Abort COMPLETE

[32mUploading output_model (2601.0 MBs): 100%|██████████| 2600999944/2600999944 [00:07<00:00, 377493550.16it/s]
```